# Expresso Store PHP 7

Tags: expresso-store, php

I have a site that has failed PCI compliance due to an older version of PHP. I need to upgrade the PHP install but need to know if Expresso Store v2.5.1 is compatible with PHP 7?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

There's no mention of PHP 7 in [Expresso Store's release notes](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/release_notes.html) and no specific mention of it in their [installation guide](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/installation.html), so one would have to take the assumption that they have not specifically tested on PHP 7 yet.

In fact, v2.5.1 was released in May 2015, 6 months before the public release of PHP 7, so it's very unlikely it has been specifically tested or updated to ensure PHP 7 compatibility.

Having said that, it's likely everything should still *just work*. PHP have specifically gone to lengths to 'make migration as painless as possible' - see [the migration guide here](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php) for more details.

I would probably feel comfortable upgrading the version of PHP, however of course you must do this on a test server rather than to your live site. Make sure error reporting is on so you can see notice of any newly deprecated functions (there's [not a lot](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php)) that are being used, and test your site thoroughly. Contact [Expresso or one of their listed professionals](https://www.exp-resso.com/support) if you have any major issues that need resolution.